# Find a retraction $r:\mathbb{R} \to [0,1].$

Tags: general-topology

> Find a retraction $r:\mathbb{R} \to [0,1].$

I was trying to find examples on retractions, but couldn't find many online. How are these retractions constructed? It seems to be related to the identity map, but I'm not entirely sure what's the connection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$r(t) = \begin{cases} 0 & t \le 0\\
                      t & t \in [0,1]\\
                      1 & t \ge 1\\
        \end{cases}$$

is a perfectly fine retraction....Or if you prefer formulae: $r(t)=\max(\min(t,1),0)$.